# Dependencies are not getting resolved in IntelliJ

Tags: java, selenium, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I have imported a Maven Java-selenium  project and for some reason these dependencies aren't getting resolved. version I am using is 3.1.0 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsed1.png) . Java version is 1.8 . Appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have `maven.resources-plugin.version` defined in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Hi yes, I have it defined. Had to clean and install Maven again. All sorted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the IntelliJ first - try to work in CMD. Remove settings.xml in your user directory if the file exists there.

settings.xml location is  C:\Users\Nidhi\.m2 - in .m2 folder you can find the seetings.xml file

1. Add environment variables:- **M2_HOME, MAVEN_HOME** - the path for these two is the maven folder in your system
   In environment variable "**Path**" add path till bin folder of Maven. Eg:-  C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin
2. **Open CMD** and cd to the folder where you have project
3. From here run **mvn clean install**

Comment: Hi Nidhi, in my .m2 folder and dont'see the .xml settings. And when I run from the cmd I get this message : C:\Users\s122092\Desktop\Automationfolder\Code repo\settlements-creditsupport-tests> run mvn clean install
'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Run this:- C:\Users\s122092\Desktop\Automationfolder\Code repo\settlements-creditsupport-tests> mvn clean

Comment: We don't have to write run. Let me know what you get after this :) I just wanting to convey we have to run the command "mvn clean" and then "mvn install" or the way to run both at the same time is "mvn clean install"

Comment: Thanks Nidhi, now the error is C:\Users\s122092\Desktop\Automationfolder\Code repo\settlements-creditsupport-tests>mvn clean
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ohhh Sharan, it means that maven is not installed correctly on your system. You will have to download maven, and set the environment variables in your system.

Comment: Add environment variables:- M2_HOME, MAVEN_HOME - the path for these two is the maven folder in your system In environment variable "Path" add path till bin folder of Maven. Eg:- C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin

Comment: Hi Nidhi, I can confirm from CMD the build is success and looks like the plugin is installed. From the image mentioned above , everything got resolved except for maven-deploy-plugin and maven-site-plugin

Comment: Really appreciate your help.  Any reason you can think of why it can't access this  particular file C:\Users\s122092\Desktop\Automationfolder\Code%20repo\settle-tests\target\classes\environment.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: I am trying to ,but this " Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded. "  :)

Answer (score 1):

The `pom.xml` should look like this:

```
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    ...
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    ...
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    ...
    </build>
</project>
```

or:

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    ...
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    ...
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    ...
    </build>
</project>
```

After editing the `pom.xml` file clean your project before new build.

Comment: Thank you, had to reinstall maven. It fixed everything.